# Backbone Marionette: How to use preventDestroy: true

Tags: backbone.js, marionette

For some reason, I can't get preventDestroy: true to work.
In my example, the loading view is removed, when the applicationsListView is showing - even though I pass in preventDestroy true.

```
  var loadingView = new App.Common.Loading.View();
  App.layout.mainRegion.show(loadingView);


  // Fetch the applications
  var fetchingApplications = App.request('application:entities');

  $.when(fetchingApplications).done(function(applications) {

    var applicationsListView = new List.Applications({
      collection: applications
    });

    App.layout.mainRegion.show(applicationsListView, { preventDestroy: true });

  });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is removed from region but not destroyed.

When you pass **preventDestroy : true**, it means that marionette doesn't itself call destroy method and event on previous view. Destroy method provides ubinding events and calls destroy on subviews and so on (https://github.com/marionettejs/backbone.marionette/blob/master/docs/marionette.view.md#view-destroy).

But call **show** with **preventDestroy : true** still clear innerHTML and put new view in region (look at **attachHtml** method in backbone.marionette/src/marionette.region.js).

It can be helpfull if you reuse your existing loading view.